Building Boost with crc library only
I want to build boost with crc library only, how to build in my case? I get err on Ubuntu 24
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++ autotools-dev libicu-dev libbz2-dev libboost-all-dev
git clone https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git
cd boost
git submodule update --init -- libs/crc/
./bootstrap.sh
./bootstrap.sh: 1: ./tools/build/src/engine/build.sh: not found
Building B2 engine..
./bootstrap.sh: 229: ./tools/build/src/engine/build.sh: not found

Failed to build B2 build engine

Ok, let's just check boost libraries list
./bootstrap.sh --show-libraries
./bootstrap.sh: 1: ./tools/build/src/engine/build.sh: not found
Building B2 engine..
./bootstrap.sh: 229: ./tools/build/src/engine/build.sh: not found

Failed to build B2 build engine


Boost.CRC is a header-only library, meaning that you do not have to build anything.
Besides, BoostDep shows that there are few dependencies: array config integer type_traits
This is a rare instance where BCP might actually work to extract a minimul subset. However, I'd simply use the release tarball of Boost and not build anything for simplicity.
UPDATE: Using BCP demonstration
So, I found the time to actually test using BCP, and it actually makes a difference:

assuming an example test.cpp
#include <boost/crc.hpp>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
  boost::crc_32_type crc;
  char const *data = "Hello, world!";
  crc.process_bytes(data, std::strlen(data));
  return crc.checksum() == 0xEBE6C6E6u ? 0 : 1;
}


get the boost release tarball and extract it
wget https://archives.boost.io/release/1.85.0/source/boost_1_85_0.tar.bz2
tar xf boost_1_85_0.tar.bz2 


extract all header dependencies:
mkdir extracted
bcp --boost=./boost_1_85_0/ --scan test.cpp extracted/


test compilation of the sample program
g++ -isystem extracted/ test.cpp 
./a.out ; echo $?




extracted.zip/tarball
Just for reference here's the 198kB zip of extracted/ folder created above: extracted.zip.
Alternatively as the 93kB tarball: extracted.tbz2
Using bcp to report the 110 headers with their copyright notices: report.html

Thanks, after your introduction I have made example. Can you check it?

I'd simply use the release tarball of Boost and not build anything for simplicity. So, get it here: https://www.boost.org/users/download/#live

Size is too much, I need crc library only, no need 760.5 MB

The release tarball isn't even close to that size, right. Again, don't build anything. Either that or use the BCP tool as mentioned in my answer to further reduce the size

Okay, so I went and tried BCP. I didn't expect much (out of experience most Boost libraries have lots of dependencies). It turns out it can extract a working subset of 110 files, totalling a mere 635kB. See the update (that includes a compiled demonstration program).

@АндрейТернити Note that Boost 1.86.0 just released updates to Boost.CRC that drop c++03 support, making it a standalone library full-stop: "Removed dependencies on Array, Config, Integer, and TypeTraits. The library is now standalone"
